# How to count the digits in a String

Tags: java, arrays

The code is close to correct, but I cannot see how I can move from `System.out.println` to a `toString()` method here, what am I missing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Histogram
{
    private int[] numCount;
    int size=0;

    public Histogram(String line)
    { 
        setList(line);
    }

    public void setList(String line)
    {
        numCount = new int[20];

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            numCount[i]=0;

        Scanner chopper = new Scanner (line);
        while (chopper.hasNextInt())
        {
            int num = chopper.nextInt();
            numCount[num]++;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            System.out.println(i+"::"+numCount[i]);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: The top part stays but i  need to replace system print wit a tostring method.

Answer (score 0):

First, in `setList()` the default value of the primitive `int` is 0. And if you're using decimal math you only need 10 digits. And remove the `println`(s);

```
public void setList(String line) {
    numCount = new int[10]; // <-- base 10
    Scanner chopper = new Scanner(line);
    while (chopper.hasNextInt()) {
        int num = chopper.nextInt();
        numCount[num]++;
    }
    // once the loop is done, you can do
    System.out.println(this); // <-- will call toString so
}
```

Next override `toString()`. You might use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) which *Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array* like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(numCount);
}
```

Finally, I personally would have preferred an implementation of `setList(String)` like

```
private int[] numCount = new int[10]; // <-- base 10

public void setList(String line) {
    for (char ch : line.toCharArray()) {
        numCount[Character.digit(ch, 10)]++;
    }
}
```